# aiplatformb.PredictRequest.Instances expects type []*structpb.Value (GCP golang client library; aiplatform)

Tags: go, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am trying to hit my Vertex AI endpoint from a Golang web application (the web server/application is running on cloud run+build). The web application has a form that I'm landing into the Details Submission, my question is, how do I take the struct received from the web application and cast it to a type accepted in the Instances field of the aiplatformb.PredictRequest struct?

```
   type Submission struct {
        MonthlyIncome                 int
        Age                           int
        Passport                      int
    }

    var Details = Submission{}


    Ctx := context.Background()
        C, err := aiplatform.NewPredictionClient(Ctx)
    
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Error 1: %v", err)
        }

        defer C.Close()

        reqs := &aiplatformpb.PredictRequest{
            Endpoint:  "{{my endpoint that is formatted correctly}",
            Instances: []*structpb.Value{},
```

I've tried hitting this endpoint externally using postman and the request below confirms the endpoint is up and running. Those values are the values of the Details Submission

```
    {
        "instances": [
            [
                29823,
                43.5,
                1
            ]
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several attempts using the client libraries and consulting documentation, the .Predict() method [which acts on a pointer to PredictionClient type] doesn't allow you to specify the schema of the vertex AI model endpoint. So the solution is to send the request via the .RawPredict() method, so making a serialized JSON (structpb) request works only if the schema implemented by the golang GCP client libarary matches that of your deployed model. Here's the GCP documentation for PredictionClient:

https://cloud.google.com/go/docs/reference/cloud.google.com/go/aiplatform/1.0.0/apiv1#cloud_google_com_go_aiplatform_apiv1_PredictionClient

Here are the necessary libraries for forming and using the RawPredict() method:

```
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "reflect"
    "strconv"

    aiplatform "cloud.google.com/go/aiplatform/apiv1"
    "cloud.google.com/go/aiplatform/apiv1/aiplatformpb"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
    "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/api/httpbody"
)
```

And here's the code:

```
// Get the form values from the web applicaiton
    income, _ := strconv.Atoi(r.FormValue("MonthlyIncome")) 
    age, _ := strconv.Atoi(r.FormValue("Age"))
    passport, _ := strconv.Atoi(r.FormValue("Passport"))


//create our struct from the form values

    Details = Submission{
        MonthlyIncome:                 income,
        Age:                           age,
        Passport:                      passport,
    }

    v := reflect.ValueOf(Details)
    body = ""


    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {

        body = body + fmt.Sprintf("%v", v.Field(i).Interface()) + ","

    }

    if last := len(body) - 1; last >= 0 && body[last] == ',' {
        body = body[:last]
    }

    Requestb = pre + body + post
    log.Println("The request string was:", Requestb)

// structure the body of the raw request
    Raw := &httpbody.HttpBody{}
    Raw.Data = []byte(Requestb)

// indentify the post request using the raw body and the endpoint
    reqs := &aiplatformpb.RawPredictRequest{
// Note  GCP Project ID, Region, and endpoint ID
        Endpoint: "projects/<PROJECT-HERE>/locations/<REGDION-HERE>/endpoints/<ENDPOINT-ID-HERE>",
        HttpBody: Raw,
    }


// CTX gets the credentials of the application service account - NOTE THE REGION
    Ctx := context.Background()
    C, err := aiplatform.NewPredictionClient(Ctx, option.WithEndpoint("<REGION-HERE>-aiplatform.googleapis.com:443"))

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error 1, connectrion:", err)
    }
    defer C.Close()

// gets the response using the credentials of the application service account
    resp, err := C.RawPredict(Ctx, reqs)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error 2, response: %v", err)
    }
    log.Println(resp)


    RespString := fmt.Sprintf("%+v", resp)
    log.Println("The Response String was:", resp)
```